# Time difference between repeat users' request_time

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, pandas-groupby

I am new to Python and need your help.

I am working on a project of a retail organization. Below mentioned data frame shows 'user_ID' containing users that visited company website only once and users that visited website multiple times. You can see that index 3,4 have same user_ID. Same is the situation in index 5,6. I need to find the **request_time_difference** for **repeat users**. i.e. a repeat user visited the website after how much time interval (any time unit is acceptable).

```
    user_ID    request_time 
0   4c3d6d10c2 3/1/2018 23:57

1   2791ec4485 3/1/2018 22:10   

2   eb0718c1c9 3/1/2018 16:34   

3   59f84cf342 3/1/2018 22:20   

4   59f84cf342 3/1/2018 22:19   

5   a11e41cdc2 3/1/2018 8:08    

6   a11e41cdc2 3/1/2018 8:13    

7   9568fb8647 3/1/2018 15:04

8   2791ec4485 3/1/2018 13:50

9   2791ec4485 3/1/2018 13:53

10  2791ec4485 3/1/2018 13:51

11  2791ec4485 3/1/2018 13:55
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, this is what your are looking for

```
df.request_time = pd.to_datetime(df.request_time)
b = df.loc[df.user_ID.duplicated(keep=False)].sort_values(['request_time']).reset_index(drop=True)
c = b.groupby(['user_ID'],sort=True)['request_time'].diff().reset_index(name='diff').reset_index(drop=True)
b.merge(c, on=b.index).drop(['key_0','index'],axis=1)
```

**Output**

```
       user_ID  request_time            diff
0   a11e41cdc2  2018-03-01 08:08:00     NaT
1   a11e41cdc2  2018-03-01 08:13:00     00:05:00
2   2791ec4485  2018-03-01 13:50:00     NaT
3   2791ec4485  2018-03-01 13:51:00     00:01:00
4   2791ec4485  2018-03-01 13:53:00     00:02:00
5   2791ec4485  2018-03-01 13:55:00     00:02:00
6   2791ec4485  2018-03-01 22:10:00     08:15:00
7   59f84cf342  2018-03-01 22:19:00     NaT
8   59f84cf342  2018-03-01 22:20:00     00:01:00
```

Comment: Thanks, Please let me know what does IIUC stand for?

Comment: IIUC stands for "If I Understood Correctly". If the answer helped you consider Up-voting & accepting the answer. Thanks.